# How can I run my protractor tests on Jenkins

Tags: protractor

I know this is a dupe but I haven't found any answer that details it all from starting.
I'm using protractor 4.0.14 and I run the tests with

`.\node_modules\.bin/protractor.cmd --specs=some\spec protractor.conf.js`

Now I want to run it on jenkins and I can't find a good answer that covers it all.

Comment: Would it be possible to tell me, what is the build tool you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Jenkins step called "Execute Windows batch command" and add the content like this:

`cd D:/xxx/xxx
protractor protractor.conf.js`